# Angular compile failing on `ng serve`, but succeeding on subsequent save

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, angular-cli, angular5

**In Angular 5, I noticed the following curious behaviour with the `ng serve` command in Visual Studio Code leading to different results on the first vs subsequent compilations.**

- Let's assume we have a trivial TypeScript error, for example `[ts] Property 'x' does not exist on type 'y'.`
- When I type `ng serve` and hit enter, the console display the TypeScript error, followed by the message `webpack: Failed to compile`.
- However, if I ignore this, open a different file and simply hit `CTRL + S`, the TypeScript errors are ignored leading to the message: `webpack: Compiled successfully`.

*This is something I noticed for quite a while. The first time the app gets compiled, it fails if there are TypeScript errors. On compiles triggered by subsequent saves however, the app compiles successfully despite those errors.*

**Why does this happen? Is there a way around this, or is this expected behaviour?**